How to fix every allocation in debugging?
I have an app written in C++ (Windows) which also used some third party libraries. In the app there are many news/deletes together with mallocs and frees. Now I met with a bug that some data on the heap is wrong, but every time I run the program, the address of that data block changes. I wonder how to make this fixed (not random) so I can easily trace the data block in debugging? I want to add some data breakpoints to it.
I have tried turn off the ASLR support in Windows Settings but the adress is still random.

You can use time travel debugging, record a trace, then replay it as many times as you like. Since it is a replay, the addresses won’t change.

@RaymondChen I've ever tried using TTD in WinDbg, it's extremely slow and hard to use.. and it seems VS has no similar feature.

Another option is to use application verifier with heap verification. There are multiple levels of heap verification. The higher levels catch more errors but also run slower.

@RaymondChen This seems rather new to me, could you please tell me some recommendations of application verifiers?

Web search for “application verifier” top hit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/application-verifier
